# Book recommendations that feature the canadian north

Tags: creative-writing, book-rec

Are there any well known (or even lesser known) books (fiction/non fiction) that are written against the beautiful backdrop of the Canadian north? i.e that talks about the nature, the history and the indigenous cultures that inhibit the boreal regions of Canada and also the canadian arctic?

Comment: Hi.  I'm afraid this sounds more like a question about *reading* than about *writing*.  Please check out the other questions (that aren't closed :-) ) on the book-rec tag; they are about resources for writing.  If you can [edit] this to be a question about writing, we can consider reopening. Thanks for your understanding.